# Ansible escape string \

Tags: ansible, escaping

Trying to add `\` before `.` on a list of IPs in Ansible.

Example:

```
"msg": "192.168.5.0"
```

Expected output:

```
"msg": "192\.168\.5\.0"
```

---

I tried this with no luck.

```
---        
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    ip: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.network }}"
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ ip | regex_replace('\.', '\\.')}}"
```

Output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "192\\.168\\.5\\.0"
}
```

---

```
---        
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    ip: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.network }}"
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ ip | regex_replace('.', '\.')}}"
```

Output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "192\\.168\\.5\\.0"
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `regex_replace` works as you expect. The double backslashes you see are the evaluation of the string by `debug`. Display, for example, the length of the string

```
    - set_fact:
        ip2: "{{ ip | regex_replace(myregex, myreplace) }}"
      vars:
        myregex: '\.'
        myreplace: '\.'
    - debug:
        msg: "length of {{ ip2 }} is {{ ip2|length }}"
```

give

```
    "msg": "length of 192\\.168\\.5\\.0 is 14"
```

It's also possible to write the string to a file. For example the template

```
shell> cat test.txt.j2
{{ ip2 }}
```

and the task

```
    - template:
        src: test.txt.j2
        dest: test.txt
```

give

```
shell> cat test.txt
192\.168\.5\.0
```